# Creating a deep copy of a multi-level list?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>> optimalPaths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>>();
```

I would like to create a deep copy of optimalPaths. The copy itself should contain no references whatsoever to optimalPaths. Would the following code work?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>> altPaths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>>();

for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>> e : optimalPaths){
    altPaths.add((ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>) e.clone()); // Create deep copy of optimalPaths
}
```

I'm not sure if there are still references within altPaths on some level.

Comment: documentation of [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()):  Returns a **shallow** copy of this ArrayList instance.  (The elements themselves are not copied.)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by yourself

```
for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>> outer : optimalPaths) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>> newOuter = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ArrayList<Task> inner : outer) {
        ArrayList<Task> newInner = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Task task: inner) {
            newInner.add((Task) task.clone());
        }
        newOuter.add(newInner);
    }
    altPaths.add(newOuter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your methodology of adding the inner levels is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @Tireless be carefull the clone method is implemented and class implements Cloneable

Comment: also be aware that this solution is creating a new list/task instance for every *position* no matter if the corresponding original instance was repeated (same task or list saved in different *positions*)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger This is a basic deep copy yes

Comment: @azro the result will eventually have more instances than the original (if original contains multiple entries with the same instance)

Comment: @Tireless you may think about voteup/accept an answer if it satisfies you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy by serialization and deserialization if Task class doesnt have any transient fields that you want to copy:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
out.writeObject(optimalPaths);

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new   ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>> copied = (ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Task>>>) in.readObject();
```

or use external class to do that: [SerializationUtils from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html)